How to combine two data frames?
I have two data frames, A and B and I need a way to combine both data frames preserving all the columns of A but only two columns of B?
I know about left_join, inner_join and full functions but I'm not sure which's the right one for my case, or there is another valid function to use.
Thank you
Gestion_union <- Gestion_Terreno%>%colnames()
  left_join(Carteta_asignada, by =c("Cedula.Cliente"="CiCliente"))

but it appers like a value
